# Unable to mock clipboard event in jasmine karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

```
copyToClip(){

    const create_copy = (e: ClipboardEvent) => {
      e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', this.value);
      e.preventDefault();
    };
    document.addEventListener('copy', create_copy);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.removeEventListener('copy', create_copy);

    alert("Copied successfuly");
  }
```

test case

```
     fit('should create', () => {
    spyOn(document, 'execCommand');
    component.value = 'Test';
    component.copyToClip()
    expect(document.execCommand).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

How to mock clipboradevent in the test case.
I have tried everything but no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this as reference and try to solve your issue!

```
desc('copyToClip method', () => {
    const params = {
        clipboardData: () => {},
        preventDefault: () => {}
    }

    beforeEach(() => {
         spyOn(params, 'preventDefault');
         spyOn(document, 'addEventListener').and.callFake((arg1, arg2) => {
             arg2(params);
         } as any);
         spyOn(document, 'execCommand').and.callFake(() => {} as any);
         spyOn(document, 'removeEventListener').and.callFake(() => {} as any);
    });

    it('should call preventDefault method', () => {
        component.copyToClip();
        expect(params.preventDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: @dhS what is the error?

Comment: Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(commandId: string, showUI?: boolean, value?: string) => boolean'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean ...... this is showing for" spyOn(document, 'execCommand').and.callFake(() => {});"

Comment: @dhS try now - updated my answer,  put any if you get these errors!